# deleting and entity through google app engine's datastore viewer does not remove the entity from the memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I 've noticed this behavior which results in consecutive gets to succeed.

Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: why should datastore operations effect memcache?

Comment: Why don't you just do memcache.flush_all() by hand?

Comment: the google admin interface should be also doing a memcache delete when someone is deleting an entry from the admin console. This results in an inconsistent state. Will be filing a bug...

Comment: the old console had a handy checkbox that allowed you to clear memcache for certain entities. I haven't managed yet through the memcache console. It's really annoying, I agree, it costs money to rebuild the whole memcache, I've got nearly 2GB at 85% hit rate or more

Comment: You should add some detail. The first assumption is the entity is in the memcache, e.g. it was requested recently. Next, you delete it from the datastore viewer online. Now, the object is still in the memcache, so application code will get it. For me, I encountered this problem with updates on entities via datastore viewer. And waiting minutes didn't resolve it too! The solution is to flush the cache using the memcache viewer online but I'm still a bit uncomfortable with needing to do that...

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to remove one single entity from memcache, painful but it works.
Now, I use Java and Objectify but I hope you'll find this useful, whatever environment and language you use.

1. Go to the page https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/memcache for your project.
2. Enter under Namespace the value "ObjectifyCache", or whatever namespace you use.
3. Under Key Type, select Java String
4. This is the tricky bit. Under Key you've got to enter the "URL-safe key" you'll find from the Datastore Edit page for your entity (https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/edit)
5. Click on Find and hopefully en entity will appear.
6. Check the box, and click on DELETE

Now you click on Find again, nothing will come up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the high-replication datastore, gets immediately after deletes may succeed and pull up the stale results.  It takes up to a few seconds for the results of each operation to appear in the results of other operations.

Memcache is operates independently of the datastore.  Some libraries like Objectify connect them,.  If you're using Objectify to cache entities and you delete something from outside of Objectify (e.g. the data viewer) you'll have to update your cache yourself.  This happens to me occasionally and I just wipe the whole memcache.

You have to find a way to work with this behavior.  The simplest (expensive and really slow) method, for example, would just be to wait ten seconds after you do every datastore operation.  Better methods might use a cache to return freshly stored or deleted entities.

Comment: I am talking about the datastore viewer in the admin console, please read the question :)